# MINIFS Returning 0

Tags: excel, min

I have a dataset that is ranked 1 to 100, and I want to return information about the lowest-numbered person. Right now I'm trying `=MINIFS(Sheet1!$A$4:$A$103,Sheet1!$B$4:$B$103,"="&Sheet2!A10)` but Excel is returning 0. It should be returning 3 because the matching criteria is ranked 3.

Comment: don't see any issue with the formula... perhaps if you can share sample data ? My only guess is the value in Sheet2!A10 is not present in Sheet1!$B$4:$B$103 range...

Comment: All or some of your values in Sheet1 Column A are possibly formatted as TEXT rather than numeric. `3(text) <> 3(number)` and would return a 0.

Comment: Formatting isn't an issue, even if I set it to look for the actual cell I am trying to return from it still shows zero.